# What is /storage/emulated/0/?

Tags: storage

Recently, I've figured out that if I delete files from `/sdcard/Download` it deletes files from `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. And if I add the files into `/sdcard/Download` it duplicates them in `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.

So what is `/storage/emulated/0/`? For what purposes do we have it in our android file system?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`/storage/emulated/0/Download` is the actual path to the files.

`/sdcard/Download` is a symlink to the actual path of `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

However, the *actual* files are located in the filesystem in `/data/media`, which is then mounted to `/storage/emulated/0` (and often other mountpoints as well)

A [Symlink](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) In computing, a symbolic link is a term for any file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution. Symbolic links were already present by 1978 in minicomputer operating systems from DEC and Data General's RDOS.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained a little bit about why it's "emulated". I believe Android does some hack to fake a FAT fs that's actually backed by something better, but I don't know the details and clicked this question hoping to learn something new.

Comment: @R.. the "emulated" IMHO points to the fact that it's an "emulated SD card" (not a real one).

Comment: @R.. It uses SDCardFS. Here's an excellent article about it: https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/ ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221031611/https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/))

Answer (score 32):

`/storage/emulated/0/` is actually `/data/media/0/` exposed through an emulated / virtual filesystem, not the actual one.

This is with reference to my previous answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/218526), but with more relevant details.

### **ANDROID STORAGE:**

On [Android 5](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_5_x_emulated):

```
/sdcard >S> /storage/emulated/legacy >S> /mnt/shell/emulated/0
/mnt/shell/emulated >E> /data/media
```

On [Android 6+](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/#runtime_permissions):

```
# for (Java) Android apps (running inside zygote virtual machine)
# "/storage to VIEW" bind mount is inside a separate mount namespace for every app
/sdcard >S> /storage/self/primary
/storage/self >B> /mnt/user/USER-ID
/mnt/user/USER-ID/primary >S> /storage/emulated/USER-ID
/storage/emulated >B> /mnt/runtime/VIEW/emulated
/mnt/runtime/VIEW/emulated >E> /data/media

# for services/daemons/processes in root/global namespace (VIEW = default)
/sdcard >S> /storage/self/primary
/storage >B> /mnt/runtime/default
/mnt/runtime/default/self/primary >S> /mnt/user/USER-ID/primary
/mnt/user/USER-ID/primary >S> /storage/emulated/USER-ID
/storage/emulated >B> /mnt/runtime/default/emulated
/mnt/runtime/default/emulated >E> /data/media
```

<sup>* `>S>` for symlink, `>E>` for emulated and `>B>` for bind mount</sup>
<sup>* `USER-ID` of current user in case of `Multiple Users` or `Work Profile`, normally `0` i.e. that of device owner</sup>
<sup>* `VIEW` is one of `read` (for apps with permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) or `write` (permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) or `default` (for processes running in root/global mount namespace i.e. outside zygote)</sup>
<sup>* There were minor differences on previous Android versions but the concept of emulation was same ever since implemented.</sup>
<sup>* For a little bit more details on Android's mount namespace implementation, see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197959/partition-gets-unmounted-automatically-in-android-oreo/200449#200449).</sup>

In short, `/sdcard` and `/storage/emulated/0` - which represent a FAT/vFAT/FAT32 filesystem - point towards `/data/media/0` (or `/mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/0` in case of [Adoptable Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable)) through `FUSE` or `sdcardfs` emulation.

Being not Android specific but generally Linux related, [symlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html) and [bind mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) (see "Creating a bind mount") are out of the scope of this question, as the question is about emulation part mainly.

### **EMULATION:**

Why the emulation is here? Emulated filesystem is an abstraction layer on actual filesystem (`ext4` or `f2fs`) that serves basically two purposes:

- Retain USB connectivity of Android devices to PCs (implemented through MTP now a days)
- Restrict unauthorized access of apps/processes to user's private media and other apps' data on SD card.

Read [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526) for details, the summary is:

Early Android devices were short on internal storage and relied on (physically) external SD cards that traditionally use FAT family of filesystem to ensure compatibility with most of the PCs (refer to Microsoft's dominance on PC world).
When the internal storage grew in size, same filesystem was shifted to internal (still called "external") SD card.
But the FAT/vFAT implementation had two major issues which were addressed by Google gradually:

- Android devices were connected to PCs directly ([USB Mass Storage](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-trusty-3.10/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt)) just as we connect a USB drive these days. UMS exposes the device at block level and disconnects the SD card from Android framework (un-mounts), thus making whole data unavailable to apps and possibly breaking many functionalities.
- FAT (being Windows' favorite in development days) was never designed to enforce UNIX permissions (mode, uid, gid and likewise [symlinks](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/fs/sdcardfs/inode.c#792), and `ioctls` like `FS_IOC_FIEMAP`). So, all data on SD card was available to all apps (since every Android app is a UNIX/Linux user and has a uid) with no restrictions, hence raising serious privacy and security concerns.

Both of these issues were addressed through emulation:

- Actual SD card storage was moved to `/data` partition (or independent /sdcard partition on some devices previously) which holds `ext4` filesystem (gradually being replaced by `f2fs`), fully implementing UNIX permissions.
- This design made using UMS impossible because whole `/data` partition could not be exposed to PC for 2 more reasons: `(1)` it contains a lot of settings and apps' data which is to be protected from other apps as well as human users. `(2)` Linux filesystems are not supported by Windows.
  So UMS was replaced with Media Transfer Protocol which is a client-server type extension to PTP - an already established protocol. [MTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) doesn't expose block device but works through software stack. MTP host runs on Android as an app (`android.process.media`) fully sandboxed in Android framework, not capable of doing any escalated tasks.

Now the apps (and MTP, which is also an app) interact with emulated storage instead of `/data/media`, achieving both purposes at the same time i.e. enforcing permission checks underneath and looking like FAT filesystem on upper surface.

Google is now implementing emulation through [sdcardfs](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/system/core/sdcard/sdcard.cpp#84) to overcome shortcomings of [FUSE](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/system/vold/model/EmulatedVolume.cpp); one major being the input/output overhead i.e. to improve read/write speeds.

**EXTERNAL STORAGE PERMISSIONS:**
Concept of [Public and Private files on external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage) can be demonstrated using an example:
Install Termux app.
Create directories `/sdcard/Android/data/com.termux/test_dir` and `/sdcard/test_dir`.
Create files `/sdcard/Android/data/com.termux/test_file` and `/sdcard/test_file`.
Execute following commands:

[image: without_storage_perm]
<sup>* You should have WhatsApp installed or select some other app's private folder.</sup>

Now Force Stop the Termux app and grant [Storage permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). Execute the commands again:

[image: with_storage_perm]

See the difference in permissions of same files and directories. This seems not to be simply possible without emulation on a native Linux filesystem when there are hundreds of apps (users) to be dealt with simultaneously. This is the filesystem emulation that lets the same file to be exposed with three different sets of permissions at same time independent of it's original permissions on actual filesystem:

```
# touch /data/media/0/test_file

# stat -c '%a %u %g %n' /data/media/0/test_file
644 1023 1023 /data/media/0/test_file

# stat -c '%a %u %g %n' /mnt/runtime/*/emulated/0/test_file
660 0 1015 /mnt/runtime/default/emulated/0/test_file
640 0 9997 /mnt/runtime/read/emulated/0/test_file
660 0 9997 /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/test_file
```

Also see [What is the “u#_everybody” UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526)

**Related:**

- [Why is the 'storage/emulated/' directory inaccessible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209067/218526)
- [How can I make a symlink (or equivalent) inside /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/218526)

Comment: +1. I think I misunderstand the part about MTP. Does MTP require a FAT filesystem on the target device to work with? If not, couldn't Google use ext4 filesystem for FUSE implementation as that could also enforce permissions checks needed for an app to access only their data in shared storage?

Comment: @Firelord when discussing emulation, focus isn't on MTP implementation. Google already made changes to MTP protocol to meet certain Android needs and possibly they could implement it through some native Linux filesystem. But the point is we need a `FAT-like permission-less filesystem` that used to be in the early days of Android to ensure backward compatibility and that meets the design of Android's External Storage concept. I've made an edit to elaborate my point.

Comment: I didn't see in your sources where you get the symbolic link, emulated mount, and bind mount correspondences from. You should also add that the "emulated" mount is actually a special filesystem mount that behaves like a bind mount.

Comment: You should rephrase `Actual SD card storage was moved to /data partition (or independent /sdcard partition on some devices previously)`. It implies that there was no `/data` directory before the move and implies that the external storage in devices got moved to internal storage, which is not possible.

Comment: The phrasing of `internal (still called "external") SD card` implies the existence of a non-removable SD card in devices.

Comment: You say `it contains a lot of settings and apps' data which is to be protected from other apps as well as human users`, but it is not true. With any file browser installed on my Android device, I can browse all files in the "emulated" SD card and I can do the same with MTP.

Comment: @Melab 1). SE is a QA site. Comments here are not for chat. Use appropriate forum for detailed technical discussion.  2). Give me a paid task and I'll provide you a line by line reference to *symbolic link*, *emulated mount*, and *bind mount* correspondences from Android source code and official documentation. 3). Emulated mount behaves more like a stacked filesystem than a bind mount. (continued)

Comment: (continued) 4). Yes this is possible. It happened. *"Actual SD card storage was moved to `/data` partition..."*. `/data/media/` is still the external storage, which used to be an actual physical SD card in earlier days. Read [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526) at least twice. It also clarifies *"Internal"* vs. *"External*" confusion. 5). *"... it contains a lot of settings and apps' data which is to be protected..."*. Here ***it*** is the `/data` partition, not external storage. Please reread. You cannot explorer `/data/` without root access.

Comment: I understand the emulation being needed for an actual SD cards, but since internal storage has a native support for permissions I don't see why it can't be used directly; this looks like a legacy implementation which should be removed. There seems to be two problems with this: 1. There's no concept of internal storage in Android, so it's emulated as external; 2. User group can restrict direct access to either full or no access. However, considering that users can't deny individual permissions but only _permission groups_, separate `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is totally useless anyway...