# Android 11 supports creation time (crtime/btime) for local folders and files?

Tags: file-system, file-transfer, file-management, mtp

is there a way on Android 11 (OnePlus 8T) for file manager to display creation time for local folders and files?

Is there in recent years the support?

Because have an iOS 14 device and use macOS 10.15 devices and the Files app and Finder shows here for local folders and files the creation time (crtime/btime).
Just like my KDE neon 5.20 and Linux Mint 20.

Are there any improvements in mtp protocol under Android 11, because so far I have heard that it is very sluggish from the user's point of view. For example, if a user copies a large file to computer (Windows 10) and at the same time copies another large file in parallel to computer, it does not work. It comes a message that you have to wait for the first copy process.

Comment: As far as I know MTP does not allow parallel operations. This is a fundamental concept of this simple protocol. May be a better alternative for you would be a file manager that uses `Androd Debug Bridge (adb)` for file-transfer. adb "feels" more like scp and there are advanced tools available such as [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync).

Comment: For the first part of the question, I think the answer is to search for and try other file manager apps. If an app doesn't have a feature you are looking for in it settings, the solution is usually to be stuck with that or look for an alternative.

Comment: *mtime* is preserved from *'adb pull -a /sdcard'*

Comment: On many devices birth/creation time is not supported by underlying filesystem as it requires `statx` syscall from kernel side and large inode size: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209243/218526

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists since the first Android version. I can confirm on Android 11 there is no such support. I asked Google a few years ago why they can't add it. I think it is a problem with Android system design. On Linux itself it is possible and there are already Linux distributions that show it by default in their file managers. By the end of 2021, all Linux distributions with GNOME (Nautilus) should display it. That means Ubuntu will soon display created date by default.

Android needs root rights or something similar for this to work (without root) and Google developers would have to do a lot of customization in Android system to use Linux kernel functions for user space programs. I think in the future Android system will support this and Google developers will add it. Maybe in Android 12 or Android 13.

Windows XP (2001) for example supports created date in Windows File Explorer for a long time and displays it by default e.g. by right click action on a file.

Just like Apple desktop systems. I know myself the System 6 (Macintosh System Software 6) from year 1988 the "Finder" (standard file manager on Mac devices) supports created date. Most likely the predecessor version of System 6 already support this.

Since iOS 11 (2017) the Files app has been integrated and shows created date for files and folders by default for users.

If you want a Linux smartphone that already supports created date then you can use a PinePhone. It uses Plasma Mobile (mobile version of the KDE Plasma Desktop) and since 2019, Dolphin (standard file manager of KDE) shows the created date.