# Android files and folder is showing wrong time and date

Tags: files, date-and-time

I've noticed that the files of my Android phone are showing the wrong time and date.

I have made a folder "New folder" and the folder was created on 3/13/21, 12:23 PM.

[image]

I renamed the folder to "New renamed folder" and the folder is showing that it was created on 3/13/21, 12:23 PM. But it should be 3/13/21, 12:32 PM.

[image]

It said it was last modified on 3/13/21, 12:23 PM. But it should be last modified on 3/13/21, 12:32 PM.

[image]

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Moving or renaming a directory (see [rename](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) syscall) changes only `ctime`, not `mtime`. See this answer to know what they are: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209243/218526

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much by design. The last modified isn't meant to change simply from renaming it. The folder modified timestamp only changes if the contents is modified such as adding, removing or renaming items within the folder.

The same goes for files. The modified timestamp shouldn't change simply from renaming or moving it. It should only change when its content is modified.