# What's the difference in contents of `/odm` and `/vendor` directories?

Tags: partitions, aosp, manufacturers

I have a little idea about the `/odm` but no idea of `/vendor` dir. Can someone please explain in the best way possible?  I looked up on Google and it didn't help.
What I'm really confused is with whether OEM's make changes to the files underlying these directories or is it the Android's source.

[Reference](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions-images#flow):

> > From /system, init launches and starts mounting all the other partitions, such as /vendor, /oem, and /odm

Comment: Is `/odm` a directory on your device? Please edit your question and only use full paths and also add your device name and vendor.

Comment: no i didn't find /odm dir in my device. a guy answered to my question regarding /proc dir. he replied https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208792/adb-shell-directories-under-root so this kinda confused me .. can i get a brief explanation?

Comment: `/odm` contains files from Original Device Manufacturer. `/vendor` contains files from SoC manufacturer. I'll share my thoughts on this when I get some time.

Answer (score 1):

***odm*** contains all specific device librarues such as sensor HAL, etc.
But ***vendor*** contains SoC specific libraries. This is because for android 9 and higher the idea is having a general/same image for all devices and using *product*, *vendor* and *oem* for every device.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain this informacion in [Source Android Documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions)

- ***ODM*** -> This partition contains original design manufacturer (ODM) customizations to system-on-chip (SoC) vendor board-support packages (BSPs). Such customizations enable ODMs to replace or customize SoC components, and implement kernel modules for board-specific components, daemons, and ODM-specific features on hardware abstraction layers (HALs). This partition is optional; typically, it's used to contain customizations so that devices can use a single vendor image for multiple hardware SKUs
- ***Vendor*** -> This partition contains any binary that isn't distributable to AOSP. If the device doesn't contain proprietary information, you can omit this partition.