# Why is the '/storage/emulated/' directory inaccessible?

Tags: stock-android, file-system, file-permissions

The **/storage** directory and the **/storage/emulated/0** directory is accessible in a non-rooted Android OS.
So, why is the ***/storage/emulated*** directory not accessible in a non-rooted Android OS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android 6+ `/storage` is a mountpoint where `tmpfs` is ([bind](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/rootdir/init.rc#330)) mounted (from `/mnt/runtime/default`) with mode `0755` i.e. it's world-readable.

For every app `/storage/emulated` is a bind mount in an isolated mount namespace, from `/mnt/runtime/VIEW/emulated` which is an emulated/virtual filesystem from `/data/media` having mode `0711` and owner `root`. So the directory is only traversable, not readable by non-root users that includes all apps.

*[VIEW](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/#runtime_permissions) is one of `read` (for apps with permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) or `write` (permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) or `default` (for all other apps and processes running in root/global mount namespace i.e. outside zygote).*

`/storage/emulated/0` is traversable, readable or writeable to apps depending on the status of manifest permissions [READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage).

These measurements are a part of Android's app sandboxing approach for better isolation, security and privacy.

**Related:** [What is /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)