# What is the "u#_everybody" UID?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, permissions, multi-user

In (multi-user) Android there are `UID`s like these:

- `u0_everybody`
- `u10_everybody`
- `u11_everybody`

Those seem different to the usual `uXX_aYY` `UID`s used for the applications. What is their purpose? Is this a way to make files available to all applications (share between applications of a user account)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated [here](https://source.android.com/devices/storage#runtime_permissions):

> Cross-user interactions are blocked using the `everybody` GID.

Android reserves UIDs / GIDs ranging from `10000` to `19999` for apps. `AID_EVERYBODY` is one of the special groups, which is used to control app's read / write ability to external storage (`/sdcard`). This group has [GID 9997](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/libcutils/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#160) for device owner. If there are profiles or multiple users, GID takes form `XX09997`, where `XX` is [UserID](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/managed-profiles#settings). So `u11_everybody` resolves to UID `1109997` and `u11_a500` to `1110500`.

Starting with Android 6, every app has it's own view of `/sdcard`, which is controlled by exposing `/data/media/[UserID]` with different permissions. This is achieved by making use of an emulated filesystem (previously `FUSE`, now `sdcardfs`) and mount namespaces. For device owner i.e. UserId `0`, `/sdcard` appears with following **three [VIEWs](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/#runtime_permissions) of permission sets:**

1. For processes running in root mount namespace such as `init`, `netd`, `vold` etc., permissions appear as `0.1015`, `0771`.
2. For processes having [`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), permissions appear as `0.9997`, `0750`.
3. For processes having [`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), permissions appear as `0.9997`, `0770`.

Screenshot shows three emulated `VIEWs` with different `gid` and `mask` values to get different permissions sets:
[image]
<sup>* Files never have executable permission i.e. `mask=6` becomes `mask=7` for files.</sup>
<sup>* `mask=23` is appearing wrong, may be a bug? In actual it's [`mask=27`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/sdcard/sdcard.cpp#171).</sup>

**Considering three distinct `VIEWs`, we come with four situations:**

1. Processes running with root privileges i.e. UID `0` have always R/W access to `/sdcard`. However if a non-privileged process running in root mount namespace wants R/W access to `/sdcard`, that would be controlled by group [AID_SDCARD_RW](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/libcutils/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#78) (GID `1015`). An example is [ADB daemon](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/adb/daemon/main.cpp#108) which runs with UID / GID `2000` but `1015` in its supplementarry groups.

Since every app runs with its unique UID in a separate mount namespace:

2. Apps without `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions won't be able to read or write to `/sdcard`.

Since every app is a member of `everybody (9997)` group:

3. Apps with `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission will be able to read the `/sdcard`.
4. Apps with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission will be able to write to `/sdcard`. So the app has full R/W access to shared / external `Public Storage` including other apps' `Private Storage`.

There's an **exception** to above rules for apps; every app has always R/W access to its own **External Private Storage**. Let's take example of app `com.xyz` with UID `10500`. Apart from internal data directory `/data/data/com.xyz`, app has a `Private Storage` directory `/sdcard/Android/data/com.xyz` with owner UID `10500`. So this directory is always readable / writable by the app.
 Please note that `/sdcard/Android/data` is [traversable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/262728) for all apps, but no R/W access.

In the same way it works for other user accounts / profiles.

**Opaque Binary Blobs: (OBB)**

Some apps need additional storage to save large files which can't be included in `.apk` file due to 100MB maximum [size limit](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files). There are two possible `obb` locations where these files are saved: `/data/media/obb/` and `/sdcard/Android/obb/`. The former was introduced before multi-users concept, so it's only available to device owner. Later is available to apps in multi-user accounts / profiles as well.
Access to former is controlled the same way as to `/sdcard`, while later is always accessible by an app as is the private external storage.

---

**RELATED:**

- [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)
- [Public and Private files on External Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage)
- [Why is the 'storage/emulated/' directory inaccessible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209067/218526)
- [How Android's permissions mapping with UIDs/GIDs works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208982/218526)
- [Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526)
- [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) (see directories occupied by an app under `APPS SPACE USAGE`).

Comment: considering the length you did go (i.e. reference parts of the source code) I can appreciate the effort put in this answer and thank you.   Here as comment also some points it'd be great to get confirmed.  1) with Android 6 different users (multi-users) are better isolated, than just mere apps (using mount namespace), true?   2) the various types (i.e. per user) of the **everybody** (`9997`) `GID` serves the purpose to give access to `/sdcard` access to `apps`, allow apps to access a common place `/sdcard` and not only their "app private" `/sdcard/Android/data/com.xyz`, correct?

Comment: there is(?? was )  this `obb` folder in Android, does this "share between users"-mechanism still work in combination with the `mount` namespace isolation?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace **1)** I have mentioned this in a comment on your [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207725/218526), can add as answer if needed. The only notable additional isolation between apps of different user accounts is the separate shared storage (i.e. `/sdcard`). **2)** Yes, `everybody` group is only to control apps' access to shared public external storage (`/sdcard`) and other apps' private external storage (`/sdcard/Android/data/*`). An app has always R/W access to its own private external storage `/sdcard/Android/data/com.xyz`. OBB section is added to answer