# Where does WhatsApp store Images/Videos when Media Visibility is disabled?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, media-files, oneplus-5

WhatsApp has a Media Visibility feature which if disabled, hides the media files from the phone gallery. It is claimed that "apparently" it reduces file storage.

> [image]

But WhatsApp still has to store media in some location, otherwise, how would it show in chats? I am able to access the media while scrolling through a WhatsApp chat, even while offline, so the media is definitely getting stored somewhere on my phone. Can I access this location? I have to access many media files that WhatsApp must have downloaded somewhere on my phone.

I am using parallel WhatsApp on my One Plus 5 Android phone. It creates a "999" directory under emulated.

Answer (score 1):

> The Android operating system uses empty `.nomedia` files to tell smartphone apps not to display or include the contents of the folder. <sup>([1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory))</sup>.

And,

> Treat all files as non-media in directories that contain a `.nomedia` file <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/media/libmedia/MediaScanner.cpp#142))</sup>.

So all that `Media Visibility` feature of WhatsApp does when disabled, is to put the newly downloaded media in a subdirectory of main media type directory, named `Private` which contains a `.nomedia` file e.g. `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/Private/`. Therefore the media files are not visible in gallery apps. But you can access that using any file explorer.

Parallel WhatsApp is a different thing, which makes use of Android [Multiple Users/Profiles](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user) feature to isolate whole `/sdcard` as well as other contents. But the media is still visible in gallery app installed within that profile. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/what-is-the-u-everybody-uid/210159#210159) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In most devices, I have used WhatsApp creates a folder in internal storage. The folder for media files is `/internal storage/WhatsApp/Media`. It contains subfolders for images, videos, etc.

```
/internal storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images
/internal storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video
/internal storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Animated Gifs
.
.
.
```

Comment: When "Media Visibility" is disabled, the media files DO NOT get stored in WhatsApp/Media directory.

Comment: @jerrymouse they do, for sure, in `Private` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'My Files' app icon - Internal Storage -
Android - media - com.whatsapp - WhatsApp - Media - WhatsApp Images

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).