# How can I run chroot on Android?

Tags: root-access, command-line

I have my chroot environment setup (Alpine Linux) in /sdcard/alpine. I try running my chroot with the following commands:

```
su
chroot alpine /bin/busybox
```

(busybox is the cli of Alpine)

I get the following error:

```
chroot: exec /bin/busybox: Permission denied.
```

How can I fix this?

My device specs:

Google Pixel XL (marlin)

Android 9.0

Rooted (obviously) with Magisk

Answer (score 2):

Binaries can't be executed on `/sdcard` because it's an [emulated](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) filesystem with [fixed file permissions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526), mounted with `noexec` mount option. Create `alpine` directory on some other filesystem e.g. `/data`:

```
~# mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/alpine/bin
```

Place your executable in newly created directory and do chroot:

```
~# cd /data/local/tmp
~# chmod 0755 alpine/bin/busybox
~# chroot alpine /bin/busybox sh
```

This will drop you to a root shell (UID 0) with changed root (`/`).

Comment: Since e.g. Termux is an app, and apps' data live under `/data`, the OP might be able to perform the whole procedure there.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman right