# AFWall+ block entire internet in Oasisfeng Island (work mode)

Tags: root-access, firewall

I have a OnePlus 6 running Android / OxygenOS 10 and have AFWall+ installed. It works fine as long as I don't use the Island app inside the island (v.4.54) of OasisFeng.
I set finally a profile which allows ALL apps to access wi-fi and in / outgoing and forward traffic is allowed to tese whether there is any service / app needed for the 'work' user (the island).
Even then, in the 'mainland' everything works normally but on the island internet is fully blocked.

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Apps in work profile have different UIDs than their main profile counterparts. A 3 digit number (like 100, or 110, or 999) is prepended to the main UID (see details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526)). You need to enable multi-user support in AFWall+ app. Then every app in work profile would appear in AFWall+ as a separate entity.

Comment: I tried this, enable 'experimental => Multi user', but in 'mainland' I could still not see the apps on the island. This thing is that I want to use the firewall in Mainland only.

Comment: It's **Experimental → Dual Apps Support**. [Multi-user](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#user_types) is somewhat different than [work profile](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#profile_types)