# What is terminal pathname to external SD card on Moto G Power?

Tags: external-sd, motorola-moto-g, terminal

I put an SD card into a Moto G Power, running Android 11.

`Settings -> Storage -> [name]` allows me to "Open with Files", which shows me the directories.
Opening "Music" shows individual albums, which contain files, which I can tap on and individually play.

So the data is fine.

I have ssh terminal access to the non-rooted phone.

What is the filesystem pathname to the mounted SD card?

Comment: `ls -1 /storage`

Comment: @alecxs, thanks, but: `ls: can't open '/storage': Permission denied`.

Comment: See [Where is the mount point for a USB stick?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218779/218526) and [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526) and [Why is the '/storage/emulated/' directory inaccessible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209067/218526)

Comment: `df | grep storage`

Comment: @alecxs, the `df` found `/storage/emulated/0` and `/storage/5D32-345F`.  The latter was what I wanted.  Thanks.  Please post this as an answer.