# How to tell if an SD Card is already internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, 9.0-pie

I have a Nokia 6.1, and Android One phone, running Pie.  Is there any way to tell if my SD card is already formatted for internal storage?

Thanks

Comment: Execute `df` on a terminal app or adb shell and share output here.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to settings>device maintenance>storage (it might be a different path for you I'm running 8.0) does it list your inserted SD card? If not then it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

Do `df | grep /mnt/expand` on a terminal app or `adb shell`. If you see a `dm-crypt` virtual volume like `/dev/block/dm-1` mounted on `/mnt/expand/[UUID]` and additionally `/mnt/expand/[UUID]` is mounted at `/storage/media`, then your external SD card is adopted as internal storage.

Otherwise it's `/data/media` mounted on `/storage/emulated`, and your SD card is mounted as Portable Storage.

**RELATED**: [What is /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)