# Where do I find the Samsung S5 private folder in adb?

Tags: adb, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, hidden, private-mode

So my dear old Samsung S5 has died in a bootloop. But before I either wipe it or trash it I wanted to recover my old photos. I've managed to pull most of them by going into their folders and then pull them in adb shell. However, some photos are in the private folder and I don't know where it is. So my question is:

Where do I find the private folder in the Samsung S5 with adb?

The Dr.fone software managed to pull some of them, so there should be some way to reach them I think.

Comment: maybe helpful https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205430

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, but I dont think the private folder has anything to do with emulations. May be wrong about that. I'm kinda new to this as well.I've tried to look through all folders with l -R, but can only find folders and the .jpg from my ordinary gallery.