# How does Windows interact with Android Internal Storage?

Tags: file-system, windows, partitions

I have a simple question which I can't find the answer for
We all know that Microsoft Windows doesn't support partition formats such as ext4 or f2fs, however even this being the case, how can it interact with Android internal storage seeing as it is formatted in ext4? (for example)

Comment: You should [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/216571/edit) your question with **how** step by step, what apps or utility programs, you believe that Windows is interacting with Android (along with what device & OS version).

Comment: On newer Android devices Windows doesn't interact directly with partitions. It uses Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) which works somewhat like a client-server protocol. All transactions occur in a request-response manner. On older devices there was USB Mass Storage (UMS) which used to expose Android partition to PC, just like a USB stick connected to PC. But that partition was formatted as FAT, not `ext4` or `f2fs`. Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't actually mount the partition, a common filesystem can be only mounted once at a time. Android actually uses MTP (media transfer protocol) to allow copying files over USB.