# Android 5.1 Emulated abd push give adb: error: failed to copy etc... remote Read-only file system

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop, shell, android-emulator

Hi I'm not trying to change the system just upload some file to the /storage/sdcard folder or /sdcard i do

`adb push etc /storage/sdcard`

and I get

`adb: error: failed to copy 'etc' to '/storage/sdcard/etc': remote Read-only file system`

the thing is only happens on android 5.1 it must be a bug i read many post about remount the system but it is not the system what i need to remount it is the userdata partition it should be writable, i have create many times the AVD maybe it is something i did but always i get the same result

if i do `df` in shell i get

```
/dev                   498.4M    28.0K   498.4M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         498.4M    12.0K   498.4M   4096
/mnt/asec              498.4M     0.0K   498.4M   4096
/mnt/obb               498.4M     0.0K   498.4M   4096
/system                  1.4G     1.2G   180.2M   4096
/cache                  61.0M    56.0K    60.9M   4096
/data                    7.7G   571.6M     7.1G   4096
```

i can't upload files , if i install es Explorer says the sdcard it is unmounted but don't shows the internal storage where it is the internal storage ? some one can tell me please what it is happen here ?

Comment: `/data/media` see this question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205430/what-is-storage-emulated-0

Comment: @Robert thank you that lead me to something but i realize the problem it is on  the emulator the usbstorage it is active the all the time then i cant access it from android i think should be a way start the emulator whiteout the usb connected  i will read thank you

Comment: the error message is misleading - target directory does not exist

Comment: @alecxs that's correct in my attempt to create the AVD from command line in the creation of a custom hardware profile it doesn't give you an option to create the sdcard it ask you if it will be SD Card support and the path for it but never ask the size to create it, you must create it whit mksdcard and then add the path to config.ini and then it works ! this only has happen to me in android-22 "5.1 lollipop" and i have upgrade everything in the SDK tools recently