# Is it reliable to save some app files in /storage/emulated/0/?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, storage

I already read that `/sdcard/` is a symlink to the actual path of `/storage/emulated/0/`.

I'm an Android app developer using Apache Cordova, wherein `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` is indeed `file:///storage/emulated/0/`.

Is it always fully reliable to save some app internal files at `/storage/emulated/0/path/to/app`, considering that the user might not have an external physical memory card on their phone?

Comment: As for the question title, the answer is "No": *emulated* is not *physical* but what's sometimes called the "internal SD card". The physical one usually shows up in `/storage` by its label, e.g. `/storage/DF8C-A1B1`. Besides, `emulated/0/` is what shows up at `/sdcard` if the device owner is "logged in". If there are other accounts, their "internal SD card" shows up as `emulated/1/` and so on.

Comment: @Izzy external SD cards are also emulated using FUSE/`sdcardfs` the way `/data/media` is. Additionally `/sdcard` (`/storage/emulated/0`) may point to a physically external SD card at least in two situations: 1) User formatted the SD card as Adoptable storage and migrated complete data to it. 2) On a device with [physical primary only](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_6) storage configuration (which isn't very common).

Comment: @IrfanLatif never heard of those, thanks for the pointer! But if you read the page behind the link, it doesn't say a word on "emulated" for this rare case – but it says for all others: "Primary shared storage (/sdcard) is emulated on top of internal storage." And that's not the "physical card" – especially not with the Nexus 6 being named an example (except for the Nexus 1, no Nexus has a slot for SD cards). You may have a point with adoptable storage, though, which I never used (why should I; that's just an emergency last resort anyhow).

Comment: @Izzy SD cards are always emulated whether using as Portable Storage or Adoptable Storage or with the *Physical Primary Only* configuration. Apps are never accessing the undelying filesystem directly in shared storage. And I haven't used any device with the *Physical Primary Only* configuration either, nor I've ever used Adoptable storage except for making experiments. But from a developer's perspective all possible situations have to be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it always fully reliable to save some app internal files at `/storage/emulated/0/path/to/app`?

No. External shared storage isn't reliable, as documented under [`getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) and other related documentation, because of multiple possible reasons:

- User or any other app with full storage access can read, modify or delete the files.
- App's private directories in external storage get deleted when the app is uninstalled.
- User might be using physically external SD card as the only primary shared external storage. So the data is lost when the card is removed.

Better use internal storage (`getFilesDir()` and sisters) for data security and reliability. For more details:

- [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)
- [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)
- [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)

Comment: thanks a lot, but when the user never had a physically external card in the first place, does `/storage/emulated/0/path/to/app` still exist?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira yes. `/storage/emulated/0` always exists. It's an emulated filesystem, the actual underlying directory is `/data/media/0`. You can please go through my answers to the linked questions for detailed explanation on this.