# Is there a reliable way to know which is the home dir of the phone?

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I'm making a program for termux and i need to access to the home directory(where are the Downloads, Android, DCIM, etc directories).

The problem is that i know that not all the phones have the '/storage/emulated/0', for example an old phone of mine had '/sdcard' instead

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The answer is it depends on the phone... There is no real "home" directory like Linux, but kind of, and in some devices it's /sdcard, others /storage/emulated/0, and in many /sdcard is just a link to the storage path (my Pixel for example). I think almost all phones have /sdcard as a link to the correct location for compatibility with older apps, but I don't know how long that will continue to exist, maybe a long time maybe not... Google is fickle.

Comment: */data/data/com.termux/files/home* or *$(realpath `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE`)*?

Comment: Read (completely and patiently) my answers to [Is it reliable to save some app files in /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232130/218526) and [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526).